Rails 7 way of auto-loading methods into controllers via engine
I'm looking into updating one of my favorite CMSs to Rails 7 that have been archived on github (PushType). Only I haven't coded Rails since Rails 6. Apparently, something about autoloading methods changed in Rails 7.  I am getting this error:
NameError: uninitialized constant PushType::ApplicationControllerMethods
          include PushType::ApplicationControllerMethods
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

for this line in the engine:
      initializer 'push_type.application_controller' do
        ActiveSupport.on_load :action_controller do
          # ActionController::Base.send :include, PushType::ApplicationControllerMethods
          include PushType::ApplicationControllerMethods
        end
      end


the engine is located in root/core/lib/push_type/core/engine.rb
the location of the definition of the controller methods in question is at: root/core/app/controllers/concerns -- within concerns directory namespacing should work but it isn't, in the controller concerns directory the methods are found in push_type/application_controller_methods.rb

I don't know what I'm doing given my hiatus from the language. but in my attempt to resolve this I have tried autoloading that concerns directory within the gem's engine like this:
    config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path("../../../app/controllers/concerns", __FILE__) <<
                             # File.expand_path("../../../app/controllers/concerns/push_type", __FILE__)
                             File.expand_path("../../../app/helpers", __FILE__)

the full engine.rb file looks like this:
module PushType
  module Core
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      isolate_namespace PushType
      engine_name 'push_type'

      config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path("../../../app/controllers/concerns", __FILE__) <<
                             # File.expand_path("../../../app/controllers/concerns/push_type", __FILE__)
                             File.expand_path("../../../app/helpers", __FILE__)

      # config.autoload_paths << "#{root}/app/controllers/concerns" <<
      #                         "#{root}/app/controllers/concerns/push_type" <<
      #                         "#{root}/app/helpers"

      # lib = root.join("lib")
      # config.autoload_once_paths.ignore(
      #   lib.join("assets"),
      #   lib.join("tasks"),
      #   lib.join("generators")
      # )

      config.generators do |g|
        g.assets false
        g.helper false
        g.test_framework  :test_unit, fixture: false
        g.hidden_namespaces << 'push_type:dummy' << 'push_type:field'
      end

      config.assets.precompile += %w(
        *.gif *.jpg *.png *.svg *.eot *.ttf *.woff *.woff2
      )

      config.to_prepare do
        Rails.application.eager_load! unless Rails.application.config.cache_classes
      end

      initializer 'push_type.dragonfly_config' do
        PushType.config.dragonfly_secret ||= Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base
        PushType.dragonfly_app_setup!
      end

      initializer 'push_type.application_controller' do
        ActiveSupport.on_load :action_controller do
          # ActionController::Base.send :include, PushType::ApplicationControllerMethods
          include PushType::ApplicationControllerMethods
        end
      end

      initializer 'push_type.menu_helpers' do
        ActiveSupport.on_load :action_view do
          include PushType::MenuBuilder::Helpers
        end
      end
    end
  end
end


It is too early, autoloading of reloadable code is not yet ready in Rails 7.
However, as it happens, that is catching a gotcha. This is why Rails 7 does not allow access to reloadable classes that early. Since the module is included in a non-reloadable class (AC::Base), it makes no sense for it to be reloadable, because reloads would have no effect for that included module.
Please, delete the custom autoload_paths configuration, and add the concerns and helpers directories of the engine to the autoload_once_paths. The non-reloadable classes and modules in that collection are available earlier.

unfortunately yield same error.

so basically editing the config.autoload_paths line to be config.autoload_once_paths in the engine as above -- didn't work for me.

is there a problem with this being in an engine initializer that was once ok?

I'd suggest using root in the configuration file instead of expand_path and ..s. Can you enable logging (Rails.autoloaders.log!), trigger the error, and share the traces and the current configuration?

oic, paths could still be wrong. i will try.

Yes, it turns out that root for the engine was inside a director called core. and i was referring to "#{root}/core/app...blah blah" all i needed to do was take out /core. totally annoying. I will give you the 100 points as well... i'm off to the now next error

Awesome. Not here for the points, but appreciate it! I follow SO just to help with Zeitwerk-related questions (I am the author). Please don't hesitate to followup or open a new one if I can help with the next errors, just mention "Zeitwerk" and I'll see it.

Dude, I appreciate you, but I am struggling with zeitwerk... been away from Rails for a while. clearing that error gave way to Zeitwerk::Error: loader that wants to manage directory /Users/bigchief/Dropbox/Code/Rails/Gems/push_type/core/app/controllers, which is already managed by blah blah. but that directory isn't even included in the first zeitwerk loader's set.

The only overlap seems to be the following.  The "rails.main" loader includes directories   {"/Users/bigchief/Dropbox/Code/Rails/Gems/push_type/core/app/controllers/concerns/push_type/filterable.rb"=>    "/Users/bigchief/Dropbox/Code/Rails/Gems/push_type/core/app/helpers/push_type/application_helper.rb"=> and rails.once has the following directories {"/Users/bigchief/Dropbox/Code/Rails/Gems/push_type/core/app/controllers/concerns"=>    "/Users/bigchief/Dropbox/Code/Rails/Gems/push_type/core/app/helpers"=>

Oh yes, that makes sense. It's an edge case because main now treats them as subdirectories of a root directory, and the lib detects a conflict. Let's configure the main autoloader to ignore those subdirectories: Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(full path to concerns, full path to helpers).

That would be in the project or the gem? Is there a way to do this from the gem so that anyone that includes the gem won't have to have the headache?

In the gem, just make sure you pass the full path to the directories. As you know, root in the engine class body gives you the root path of the engine. Also, good to know that config.autoload_* is per engine. Rails then merges them all later during the boot process.
